# Can I use my PS3 on a TV with HDMI 2.0 ports?

Tags: ps3, hdmi

I'm thinking of buying a new 4k TV, one I have my eyes on only has 3 HDMI 2.0 connections. I read that 2.0 is backwards compatible with 1.4.

Does that mean it will work on my PS3 Slim 250 GB model?

Comment: Something wrong with this question or is someone being trigger happy with their downvote privilege as can be seen with the recent new questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [**this Reddit discussion**](https://www.reddit.com/r/PS4/comments/3aqpjw/i_cant_get_a_straight_answer_does_ps4_support/), HDMI 2.0 ports still support HDMI 1.x cables, so you should be able to use your new TV with your PS3 and it's original HDMI cable.

However, [**this poster**](http://community.us.playstation.com/t5/Consoles-Peripherals/Does-the-Playstation-3-support-HDMI-2-0/td-p/45842782) on the Playstation Forums is having difficulty getting his PS3 to recognise the newer HDMI 2.0 cables. A responder posts this:

> I couldn't help but notice you have the same TV as me... [snip] I can confirm for you that my ps3 does work with standard HMDI 1.4 cables...

So yes - as long as you continue to use HDMI 1.4 cables, your PS3 will work on a TV that has HDMI 2.0 ports. Your mileage may vary if you try and upgrade to HDMI 2.0 cabling.

Comment: Cheers for your answer, and thanks for not changing your name to Eggman...

Comment: @user35594 - glad to help, on both counts :-)